# bike pump hose split

Tags: pump

My bike pump hose keeps splitting in two halves. First time it split near the base of the pump (which i fixed by discarding the smaller piece and inserting the longer one to the base of the of pump) and now it has split right in the middle. I searched the internet but could find nothing like this reported before. I am perplexed, what could be the likely reason? I have been keeping the pump on the floor inside a closet for about four years and the two splitting incidents took place in the last month. Nothing else in the closet or the house have damaged. It looks like a very sharp clean cut:

[image: bike pump hose split]

Thanks!

Comment: If the hose is just snapping like that it must be plain plastic, with no fiber reinforcement.  This would indicate that the pump is a very cheap one and you'd be better served by replacing the whole thing.

Comment: If all else fails you may be able to purchase a replacement hose depending on the brand and head type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its at a point where the hose bends naturally, then it could be weakened by flexing.

What about temperature?  Could it be the hose is simply perishing with age?  Heat accelerates aging, so if its been hot or in sunlight for a while it will age quicker.

Look very closely at the split.  Is it smooth or slightly rough?  If its smooth, consider a sharp object may be involved.   Or is the hose getting caught under a weight, or in a door or track?

Do you have cats or kids ?  One has claws and the other can have scissors.

**Answer**: Time for a new length of pressure hose with the right Internal Diameter.  Outer diameter is less important, and matters only at the ends..  inside  Get a couple metres and fit it.  You may need some small hose clamps too.    Do try and repair it, a good pump should last a hundred years.

Comment: "A good pump".  A cheap pump can be the bane of your existence.

Comment: I will replace the pump which seems to be the bane of my existence. :)